# freatherlight unlinked images

Tags: javascript, ghost-blog, featherlight.js

I am having some troubles with featherlight, for some reason it won't work, I am using Ghost as a platform and I have several images added to a post using Ghost's markdown, for featherlight to work I need link to those images with a class in order to bind them featherlight, so I am using the following jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var src = $this.attr('src');
        var a = $('<a/>').attr('href', src).addClass('lightbox');
        $this.wrap(a);
        });
    });
```

and calling featherlight

```
    $("a.lightbox").featherlight({
        closeOnClick: 'anywhere',
    });
```

I look at my inspector in Chrome and have no errors and the images are wrapped in  tags just fine with the proper class:

```
<a href="/content/images/2015/05/IMG_0150.jpg" class="lightbox">
    <img src="/content/images/2015/05/IMG_0150.jpg" alt="Beautiful Girls">
</a>
```

One thing I noticed that right after the  tag I get a span class for each of the image in the post

```
<span class="overlayContainer" style="top: 1603px; left: 1108.5px;"></span>
```

I am very new to JS and jQuery so this might be a very simple fix.

Comment: here is a copypasta of the source http://pastebin.com/GDirpYGL

Comment: put your `$("a.lightbox").featherlight({closeOnClick: 'anywhere',});` block inside `$(document).ready(function(){});`. Also remove the extra comma after `'anywhere',`.

Comment: You may want to check out http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/gallery.html

Comment: @jcuenod I have, but since I had trouble implementing just the Lightbox I removed it in order to minimise the points of failure, but this indeed will get added. :) thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put your `$("a.lightbox").featherlight({closeOnClick: 'anywhere',});` block inside `$(document).ready(function(){/* ... */});`. Also remove the extra comma after `'anywhere',`

Your code beocomes

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var src = $this.attr('src');
        var a = $('<a/>').attr('href', src).addClass('lightbox');
        $this.wrap(a);
    });

    $("a.lightbox").featherlight({
        closeOnClick: 'anywhere'
    });
});
```

Comment: Removing the trailing comma is unnecessary. It's invalid for JSON but it's not a problem in js.

Comment: Correct, or bind on `document` and use the `filter` option.

Comment: @Ejay I get: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).featherlight is not a function`  `(anonymous function) @ (index):162`

Comment: make sure you add the featherlight library before this code. Also check output of `console.log($("a.lightbox"));` before applying feathelight. It should list elements.

Comment: @Ejay same error, console output returns the expected output `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/noelboss/featherlight/1.2.3/release/featherlight.min.js"><‌​/script> <script> code from above </script>` thats how my sourcecode is looking.

Comment: OK, i had to call     `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.0.min.js"></script>` specifically. now works like a charm